# Sympy factorize derivatives

Tags: python, sympy

How can I factorize derivatives in Sympy ?

For example:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols("x")
f=Function("f")(x)  
g=Function("g")(x)  
factor(Derivative(f,x)+Derivative(g,x))
```

This gives the following output:

```
Derivative(f,x)+Derivative(g,x)
```

What I want is:

```
Derivative(f+g,x)
```

I find a workaround by using a non commutative symbol "dx" which stands for the derivative but this assumption does not work with the factor function and more complex problem:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols("x")
dx=symbols("dx",commutative=False)
f=Function("f")(x)  
g=Function("g")(x)  
factor(g*dx*f+g*dx*g))
```

Output:

```
(f(x) + g(x))*g(x)*dx
```

The result should be:

```
g(x)*dx*(f(x)+g(x))
```

Or ideally:

```
g(x)*Derivative(f+g,x)
```

Comment: That's a complicated issue in SymPy. Basically it requires rewriting the way function objects are created. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4787